# Is there timeout on Sqlite transactions?

Tags: sqlite, transactions, timeout

Is there any limitations on sqlite transactions? For example inserting large amount of data in one transaction can cause a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can make transaction as big as you like (as long as you have disk space) and as long as you like (as long as nobody else wants to access the database).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I would like to tell that - SQLITE is not a full fledged database. It is there to repalce file.open() and consider it as writing structured data to local file.

It is not advisable to load large data (migrate) using bigger transactions. Better use smaller dataset if ever wanted transactions. Transactions could lock DB state and make other queries to block.